# npm install errors; npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvm

Noob here, I am trying to use bash terminal to install npm modules and use as a Remote-WSL terminal.

Some background info, I am using VSCode as my code editor. I am trying to make a javaScript app using node.js. I set up Ubuntu terminal on Windows 10.

After updating npm to the latest version I started getting these errors when trying to install express, using `npm install express --save`

```
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
// etc, etc, etc 500x...

npm WARN bashdemo@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN bashdemo@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /mnt/d/Program Files/Workspace/bashDemo/node_modules/bytes
npm ERR! dest /mnt/d/Program Files/Workspace/bashDemo/node_modules/.bytes.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/mnt/d/Program Files/Workspace/bashDemo/node_modules/bytes' -> '/mnt/d/Program Files/Workspace/bashDemo/node_modules/.bytes.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/aaron/.npm/_logs/2019-11-14T21_41_32_512Z-debug.log
```

This issue persists regardless of the module I am trying to install....

Even after reverting to the original version of npm that was working, 6.12.1, these errors persist.

If I run `npm install` I get

```
npm WARN bashdemo@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN bashdemo@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 0.636s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I tried clearing my caches, resetting, uninstalling, turning the linux subsystem off/on, restarting my computer each time, and reinstalling Ubuntu then going through the set up process, updating, upgrading, installing nvm using curl script on the github page about 3x now.

I tried, unmounting and remounting my /mnt/c/ following guides for previously reported issues that seemed similar. Which only served to make things worse, (prompting a reset and reinstall of Ubuntu terminal).

Comment: Not sure if it's the same thing, but this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58414196/861835

Comment: I attempted this earlier, but it turned out I somehow missed the step on reinstalling node back onto my windows machine when I uninstalled it previously to run a clean installation of node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me resolve this issue. Was a small and easy to overlook mistake on my part >.>

In short, It was resolved by just reinstalling node.js on windows... :/

During my update process, I uninstalled node.js to perform a clean installation. If I ran `node -v` in the bash terminal, I would see the version number and know that it was installed within the linux subsystem.

However, if I were to check in Powershell for node.js, I would find that it was not installed as I did not find a version number returned. I must have missed reinstalling Node back onto my machine. I Likely installed in a different place and in my nubbish confusion of uninstalling and reinstalling things, I neglected to put it back where I had it installed originally.

In conclusion, if you are using the linux subsystem as your command line terminal when working with node.js, make sure Node was properly installed on Windows.

P.S. I was not having the drive mounting issue others were having when getting this same type of error, so my issue resolved by reinstalling Node in the place I previously had it beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can get this error is that the windows C: drive is mounted with root ownership rather than user ownership.

See: [chmod chown wsl improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/)

The short answer is that you need to remount the C: drive with new permissions

```
sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=22,fmask=111
```

Answer (score 0):

For me turning the antivirus off worked. It was not allowing edits to the folder.